# how to instantiate a form directly in a collection

Tags: vba, ms-access

I use a "OrderLines" form in several ways (by order number, by product code, by customer, by supplier, ...).
Each instance of it it able to launch a new instance of it.

Example:

- the first instance of this form lists all order lines of a specific order
- by doubleclicking on a product ID in this instance, the user launches a second instance of this form that lists all order lines regarding this specific product
- by doubleclicking on a customer code in the second instance, the user launches a third instance that lists all order lines regarding this specific customer
- and so on...

To instantiate the form "OrderLines", I use this kind of code:

In "declarations" module:

```
    Global cForms As Collection
    Global fForms(20) As Form
```

In calling form:

```
    x = boring_function_to_find_a_free_room_in_fForms()
    Set fForms(x) = New Form_OrderLines
    fForms(x).SetFocus
    cForms.add Item:=cForms(x), Key:=CStr(cForms(x).Hwnd)
```

My question is : instead of using boring_function_to_find_a_free_room_in_fForms() and fForms(x) to instantiate the form, is there any way to instantiate it "directly" in the collection?

I've tried:

```
    cForms.add Item:=(New Form_OrderLines)
```

It works BUT :

1) each new instance closes the previous instance

2) I don't know how to write the equivalent of "Key:=CStr(cForms(x).Hwnd)"

Comment: Why do you need cForms, what are you using it for that the array can't accomplish? Also, to instantiate in the array its Set fForms(boring_function_to_find_a_free_room_in_fForms()) = New Form_OrderLines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the array when you have the collection.

This is the *good'ol'code* that's been used to track multiple instances by their hWnd:

```
Option Compare Database

Public colForms As New Collection
Public mintI As Integer

Public Sub NewFormInstance(frmOld As Form_MyForm)

    Dim frm As Form_MyForm
 
    Set frm = New Form_MyForm
 
    mintI = mintI + 1
    colForms.Add Item:=frm, Key:=frm.Hwnd & ""
    frm.Caption = "My Form " & mintI
    DoCmd.MoveSize (mintI + 1) * 80, (mintI + 1) * 350  
    frm.Visible = True

End Sub
```

You be able to easily adapt this to your scenario.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. even if I don't understand how it works: how the form instance can survive to the death of "frm" variable at the end of  NewFormInstance() execution?

Comment: `frm` doesn't "die" but is stored in the collection for later to be identified by its key.