# MS Access: instantiating a form within a custom class

Tags: vba, forms, class, ms-access

I am trying to instantiate an existing form (frmVisibleForm) in my project from within a custom class module (clsMBox) and manipulate its properties from there too. I want to be able to use events from the form.

*What I expect to happen:*

1. The Form frmVisibleForm is instantiated but invisible
2. The Form gets set to Modal
3. The Form gets set to Visible
4. The Form gets Focus

*What happens:*

Nothing. No form shows up, no error messages, no prompts, nothing happens at all when running the test module´s function. Its my first time trying out custom classes in access so maybe I made some fundamental error but I can't figure out why it doesn´t work the way I thought it would. Appreciate any help.

Here is the code I have so far:

***The Form (frmVisibleForm):***

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Event DataInput(InputValue As String)
```

(No actual events thus far)

***The Custom Class Module (clsMBox):***

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim WithEvents cls_frmVisibleForm As Form_frmVisibleForm

Private Sub InstantiateForm()

    Set cls_frmVisibleForm = New Form_frmVisibleForm

    With cls_frmVisibleForm
    
        .Modal = True
        .Visible = True
        .SetFocus
        
    End With

End Sub
```

***The Module I try to test it from (mdlTestMBox):***

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function ClassTest()

    Dim mbox As clsMBox
    
    Set mbox = New clsMBox
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to either make `InstantiateForm` a *public* method, and then call that, or rename it to initialise:

```vb
Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Static cls_frmVisibleForm As Access.Form

    Set cls_frmVisibleForm = New Form_frmVisibleForm

    With cls_frmVisibleForm
    
        .Modal = True
        .Visible = True
        .Move 0, 0
        
    End With

End Sub
```

To open and close an instance of the form:

```vb
Public Function ClassTest()

    Static mbox As clsMBox
    
    Set mbox = New clsMBox
    
    Stop
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Forms(0).Name
  
End Function
```

Comment: Yes, remove that.

Comment: Ok, that resolves the error but the form is still not showing up.

Comment: Try to first Dim it as a form. See expanded answer, please.

Comment: Same thing unfortunately. What happens is the editor loses focus and the Access window gains focus. But the form is not being displayed. I tried setting it to pop-up but that did not solve it either.

Comment: Then try to remove the Modal.

Comment: ok, the form does open. I had to use a custom module for centering it on my primary screen to actually see it, otherwise it was someplace off-screen. The issue is, it opens only for a fraction of a second, then immediately disappears. Same with Modal or without it.

Comment: Perhaps you can Move it to top-left - see answer, please.

Comment: That works too, but only reliably with a single screen. It still only pops up for a fraction of a second, then disappears. I'd actually lik it to stay open.

Comment: OK. Then it may be caused by a known flaw of Access having problems when calculating form and screen sizes using hi-resolution screens as these measures are handled as Integer, not Long, for historical reasons. There is, sadly, no time frame for a resolution of this limitation.

Comment: I have a module that can center the form on the screen correctly when run from the form's on_load event, doing all the conversions between pixels, twips, long and integer for me, So that's not a real issue, just an inconvenience. I don't get why the form does not stay open. Does it just terminate the host class instance as soon as its done running through the instantiation of the form?

Comment: Yes. The instance of the form must be kept "live" somehow. One method is to declare the object and class as _Static_. Se extended answer, please. Another method is to add the handle of the form to a _Collection_.

Comment: OK, thx! So it was expected behavior after all. Is there some other way to keep the instance 'live' for like having a user press a button on the form, which then raises an event, does some stuff and then manually closes the instance after all that is complete? If I use a static class, have a button raise an event on the form, then consume the event in the host class by also unloading the form, would that properly terminate the host class?

Comment: Yes, hold it in a collection - as in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42735065/3527297).